# Remove same values rows over different column mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I 'm stuck on a very basic problem, I want to skip the row which has duplicate values over three columns.

Table feeds

```
id,type,user_id,friend_id,date
1, 'friend', 4 , 5 , 5/5/2010
2, 'friend', 5 , 4 , 5/5/2010
```

Now this is how the data is saved (I can't change the saving module)

since both have same thing, so I want to pick them only as a 1 row not 2.
I don't want to validate and remove it at PHP end, b/c if I'll do at PHP the pagination would be disturb

Edit:

Table Structure

```
create table `feed` (
    `id` double ,
    `type` blob ,
    `user_id` double ,
    `type_id` double ,
    `date` datetime 
); 
insert into `feed` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`, `type_id`, `date`) values('78','friends','1314','1313','2012-09-03 19:48:14');
insert into `feed` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`, `type_id`, `date`) values('79','friends','1313','1314','2012-09-03 19:48:14');
insert into `feed` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`, `type_id`, `date`) values('80','friends','1314','1312','2012-09-03 19:49:07');
insert into `feed` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`, `type_id`, `date`) values('82','friends','1313','1312','2012-09-03 19:49:09');
insert into `feed` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`, `type_id`, `date`) values('84','friends','1315','1312','2012-09-03 19:49:24');
insert into `feed` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`, `type_id`, `date`) values('86','friends','1315','1313','2012-09-03 19:49:33');
insert into `feed` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`, `type_id`, `date`) values('87','friends','1313','1315','2012-09-03 19:49:33');
insert into `feed` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`, `type_id`, `date`) values('97','friends','1317','1312','2012-09-03 19:55:06');
insert into `feed` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`, `type_id`, `date`) values('99','friends','1313','1317','2012-09-03 19:56:01');
insert into `feed` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`, `type_id`, `date`) values('100','friends','1317','1313','2012-09-03 19:56:01');
insert into `feed` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`, `type_id`, `date`) values('101','friends','1315','1317','2012-09-03 19:56:58');
insert into `feed` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`, `type_id`, `date`) values('102','friends','1317','1315','2012-09-03 19:56:58');
insert into `feed` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`, `type_id`, `date`) values('104','following','1313','1193','2012-09-03 19:59:39');
insert into `feed` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`, `type_id`, `date`) values('105','following','1313','1308','2012-09-03 19:59:51');
insert into `feed` (`id`, `type`, `user_id`, `type_id`, `date`) values('106','following','1313','1098','2012-09-03 19:59:58');
```

Comment: do you want to eliminate same friendship records? (like in given records "5 is friend of 4" means "4 is friend of 5")

Comment: yes I want to eliminate the same friendship values, b/c 4->5 and 5->4 are same

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green button.

Comment: @Zar Yes will do that, but let me try that in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here is the ultimate solution! If the same friendship pair (reversed) exists it only takes the one where user_id>friend_id.

```
SELECT DISTINCT type, user_id, friend_id, date 
FROM table t1 
WHERE t1.user_id > t1.friend_id 
    OR NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM table t2 
            WHERE t1.type=t2.type AND t1.date=t2.date 
            AND t2.user_id = t1.friend_id AND t2.friend_id = t1.user_id 
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is DISTINCT(). That allows you to group the table by that column and remove duplicates.

Just make sure in your select statement that you also select the other field columns as well:

> SELECT `id`, DISTINCT(`type`), `user_id`, `friend_id`, `date` FROM TABLENAME

Comment: Taking his example, `user_id` aren't equal in both rows, hence they won't get "merged" with your code as he wants?

Comment: No this distinct doesn't work in this case , see this when I run query    http://screencast.com/t/eYm3JWNrXPCp

Comment: @Zar, it should grab 1 of the user_ids.

Comment: @MajinVegeta: Hm... you might need to add GROUP BY `type` between the WHERE and ORDER clause.

Answer (score 1):

You could perform a `JOIN` on the table itself, which should do what you are looking for.
Something like this might do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName a
JOIN tableName b ON a.user_id = b.friend_id
```

Comment: won't work. it does not even take distinct `type` and `date` columns.

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of those duplicate records by running:

```
DELETE FROM table t1 WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM table t2 
    WHERE t1.type=t2.type AND t1.date=t2.date 
      AND t2.user_id = t1.friend_id AND t2.friend_id = t1.user_id 
      AND t1.user_id > t2.user_id 
  )
```

Then you can get distinct friendship records with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type, user_id, friend_id, date FROM table
```

Also, you can write a DB trigger that fires on INSERT, that checks if a duplicate (with reversed user_id and friend_id) already exists. If exists it does ROLLBACK, else allow INSERT.